# How to get stack trace in Processing debugger

Tags: java, debugging, processing, breakpoints, processing-ide

Is there any way to show a stack trace in the Processing 3 debugger (Java mode)? Not by catching an exception. I know about `e.printStackTrace()`. I want to print a stack trace in the debugger at a custom breakpoint.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to view the stack in Processing's debugger. The Processing debugger is designed to be pretty barebones. If you really need this functionality, consider switching to a more advanced IDE like Eclipse or Intellij. Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) is a tutorial I wrote on using Processing in Java.

But one thing that you might try is manually printing out the stack trace by creating a new `Exception`:

```
new Exception().printStackTrace();
```

This will print out a stack trace to the console without actually throwing an exception. Put this line right before your break point to see the breakpoint's stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

If you set an exception breakpoint all IDEs will stop when the exception is thrown and show you the current stack. You cannot get a stack trace after the fact unless you print/log it somewhere at the time the exception happens.